# How to verify if a span of vectors is a subset of another span of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

> $\displaystyle b_1=\left\lbrace\frac{12}{9},\frac{12}{9},2\right\rbrace^T,b_2=\{-18,-18,21\}^T$ and $\displaystyle v_1=\{-1,-1,2\}^T,v_2=\{3,3,-3\}^T$. $b_1 \in \operatorname{Span}\{v_1,v_2\} \text{ and } b_2 \in \operatorname{Span}\{v_1,v_2\}$. Can we conclude that (Without performing further verification) $\operatorname{Span}\{b_1,b_2\} \subseteq \operatorname{Span}\{v_1,v_2\}$? What about $ \operatorname{Span}\{v_1,v_2\} \subseteq  \operatorname{Span}\{b_1,b_2\}$?

As the question has provided, both $b_1,b_2$ belongs to the span of $v_1,v_2$. However, the answer key only pointed out that we can only conclude $\operatorname{Span}\{b_1,b_2\} \subset \operatorname{Span}\{v_1,v_2\}$ but not $ \operatorname{Span}\{v_1,v_2\} \subset  \operatorname{Span}\{b_1,b_2\}$ without any further explanation.

Is the fact that both $b_1 \in \operatorname{Span}\{v_1,v_2\} \text{ and } b_2 \in \operatorname{Span}\{v_1,v_2\}$ implies that $\operatorname{Span}\{b_1,b_2\} \subseteq \operatorname{Span}\{v_1,v_2\}$ ?

More generally, as my question's title suggests, how do I verify if a Span of vectors is a subset of another span of vectors? (I am capable of verifying if a single vector belongs to a span of vectors) but I can't make any connections between the two

Comment: You should write $span \{b_1,b_2\} \subseteq span \{b_1,b_2\} $ and not $span \{b_1,b_2\} \in span \{b_1,b_2\} $

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $b_1 \in \text{Span}(v_1, v_2) $ and $b_2 \in \text{Span}(v_1, v_2)$, then $\text{Span}(b_1, b_2) \subset \text{Span}(v_1, v_2)$.

*Proof:*

$b_1 \in \text{Span}(v_1, v_2) $ $\implies $ $b_1 = k_1 v_1 + k_2 v_2$. Similarly, $b_2 \in \text{Span}(v_1, v_2)$ $\implies $ $b_2 = c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2$.

Hence, an arbitrary vector $w \in \text{Span}(b_1, b_2)$ satisfies

\begin{align}
  w &= m_1 b_1 + m_2 b_2\\
    &= (m_1 k_1 + m_2 c_1) v_1 + (m_1 k_2 + m_2 c_2 ) v_2 
\end{align}

This implies $w \in \text{Span}(v_1, v_2)$. Hence, $\text{Span}(b_1, b_2) \subset \text{Span}(v_1, v_2)$.

*End Proof*

If $b_1 \in \text{Span}(v_1, v_2) $ and $b_2 \in \text{Span}(v_1, v_2)$, then $\text{Span}(v_1, v_2) \subset \text{Span}(b_1, b_2)$ is in general False.

*Counterexample*

Take $b_1 = b_2 = v_1$. Then, Span$(b_1, b_2)$ = Span$(v_1)$. Hence,  $\text{Span}(v_1, v_2) \nsubseteq \text{Span}(b_1, b_2)$

*Response to comments:*

If $b_1 \in \text{Span}(v_1, v_2) $ and $b_2 \in \text{Span}(v_1, v_2)$, then $\text{Span}(b_1, b_2) \subset \text{Span}(v_1, v_2)$.

Now if $\text{Span}(b_1, b_2) \subset \text{Span}(v_1, v_2)$  and dim(Span($b_1, b_2$)) $=$ dim(Span($v_1, v_2$)), then indeed Span($b_1, b_2$) $=$ Span($v_1, v_2$). This follows from a general rule that any subspace $A$ of a vector space $V$ satisfying dim$(A) = $ dim($V$) implies that $A = V$.

Comment: So if I have another vector, $v_3$ that is in the span, can I say then: Span($v_1,v_2,v_3$) $\subset$ Span($b_1,b_2$)? (Just this seems bit weird as we are having a 3-vector set span as a subset of a 2-vector set span)

Comment: yes that is true. I edited my answer to insert a short proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have done some further "investigation" I found that in this particular questions, $b_1,b_2$ also are in Span($v_1,v_2$). So I think we can conclude that, along with Span($v_1,v_2$) $\subseteq$ Span($b_1,b_2$), Span($v_1,v_2$) $=$ Span($b_1,b_2$) (Since they are both subset of each other, so they must equal). Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes that is true. Another way to see this is that the subspace Span$(v_1, v_2)$ has the same dimension as the parent vector space Span$(b_1, b_2)$ so they must be equal.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is much clear now

Answer (score 2):

As @ironX & @pietro said, and also by definition of vector spaces, they contain the $Span$ of any subset of themselves. But for inverse, also as they said truly, you can't conclude it. Of course, if you are curious to find such condition:

If you have $\dim(Span\{ v_1, v_2 \}) \leqslant \dim(Span\{ b_1, b_2 \})$, beside $Span\{ b_1, b_2 \} \subseteq Span\{ v_1, v_2 \}$, then you can conclude the inverse: $Span\{ v_1, v_2 \} \subseteq Span\{ b_1, b_2 \}$ and so they become equal with equal dimension.

In some cases investigating the independency of vectors can help much.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you cannot say that $Span\{v_1,v_2\} \subseteq Span\{b_1,b_2\}$ in general. To see that consider the trivial case where:
$v_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $v_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

and $b_1=b_2=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

It is clear that $Span\{b_1,b_2\}=Span\{b_1\} \subseteq Span\{v_1,v_2\}$ but not the contrary (you cannot generate $v_2$ using $b_1$).

Now, about your question "Is the fact that both $b_1 \in Span\{v_1,v_2\} \text{ and } b_2 \in Span\{v_1,v_2\}$ implies that $Span\{b_1,b_2\} \subseteq Span\{v_1,v_2\}$ ?" The answer is yes.

To see that, go back to the definition of $Span\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ : it is the set of vectors that can be genereated by a linear combination of $(v_1,...,v_n)$.

In your case, as $b_1$ and $b_2$ can be computed as linear combinations of $v_1$ and $v_2$, thus any linear combination of $b_1$ and $b_2$ can be computed as linear combinations of $v_1$ and $v_2$. Hence the result.

Now a general method to see if a Span of vectors $b_1,...,b_k$ is a subset of another span of vectors $v_1,...,v_k$ is to check if for all i in 1,...,k $b_i$ is a linear combination of $v_1,...,v_k$.

Hope it helps you!